# Using polyglossia's \greeknumeral with the endnotes package

Tags: polyglossia, endnotes

I'd like to number my endnotes with greek numerals. To do this I loaded the `polyglossia` package and created a command to wrap around its `\greeknumeral` command.

I've found this all works exactly as desired for footnotes, but is bafflingly uncooperative for endnotes. Specifically, XeLaTeX complains that `\@xendnote` is used in a way that doesn't match its definition. However, I don't use the `\endnote[num]{text}` version of the command at all, so I'm unsure what about the `\greeknumeral`s makes `\@xendnote` think it sees use.

I'd appreciate any hints as to what's going wrong, or suggestions on how to get endnotes to work with greek numerals. My minimal (non-)working example is below.

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{endnotes,polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}[Script=Greek]{CMU Serif}

\renewcommand\thefootnote{\greek{footnote}}%greek numerals - works fine  
\renewcommand\theendnote{\greek{endnote}}%greek numerals - doesn't work

\makeatletter
\def\greek#1{\expandafter\@greek\csname c@#1\endcsname} %in analogy with \roman
\def\@greek#1{\greekfont\greeknumeral #1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\endnote{en1}...
\theendnotes
\end{document}
```